# Изменение цвета текста в NSTableCellView при выделении ячейки

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Есть таблица с одной колонкой (список диалогов).

Есть класс, унаследованный от NSTableRowView с:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    if isSelected {
        NSColor(red: 0.375, green: 0.515, blue: 0.657, alpha: 1).set()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

View, используемые в `viewFor tableColumn, row`, унаследованы от NSTableCellView c:

```
override var backgroundStyle: NSBackgroundStyle {
    didSet {
        if backgroundStyle == .dark {
            //делаем текст белым
        } else if backgroundStyle == .light {
            //возвращаем прежние цвета
        }
    }
}
```

И вроде бы в целом-то, все отрабатывает: [image: на долю секунды]

Однако при нажатии на любую из ячеек этих самых диалогов, firstResponder получает textView для ввода сообщений в выбранный диалог. И в этот момент происходит вот такое: [image: чернь какая-то].
Где я ошибся?

Возможно, ответ найдется по ссылке, найденной [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463871/change-selection-color-on-view-based-nstableview#comment39053305_9594543).
Посмотрю - отпишусь.

Comment: а что должно происходить?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko в целом, можно чтобы при смене респондера не происходило ничего. То бишь, фон оставался синим, а текст - белым. Либо же текст оставить белым, а фон чутка осветлить, чтобы, так сказать, понимать, что фокус уже не на таблице. Где определяется фон выделенной ячейки когда таблица, в которой она выбрана - не firstResponder?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на собственный же вопрос. Нашел ответ где и ожидал.

Все решилось добавлением одного условия в код:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    if isSelected && isEmphasized {
        NSColor(red: 0.375, green: 0.515, blue: 0.657, alpha: 1).set()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    } else if isSelected {
        NSColor(red: 0.929, green: 0.941, blue: 0.962, alpha: 1).set()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

Не совсем то, что я искал, но установить другой цвет фона при уходе firstResponder с tableView мне удалось.